# How to I query a datastore in python and post to a jinja2 template?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm trying to create a form that a user can input a stadium address submit the form, query the Google App Engine Datastore and confirm that the address is correct, then post to a jinja2 template that the address is correct or these are the addresses that are nearest to that point.  I'm using python.

Here is the class:

```
class Search(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        addressNumber = self.request.get('addressNumber')
        streetName = self.request.get('streetName')
        unitNumber = self.request.get('unitNumber')
        city = self.request.get('city')
        state = self.request.get('state')
        zipCode = self.request.get('zipCode')


        q = BigView.query()
        q = q.filter(BigView.addressNumber == addressNumber)
        q = q.filter(BigView.streetName == streetName)
        q = q.filter(BigView.unitNumber == unitNumber)
        q = q.filter(BigView.state == state)
        q = q.filter(BigView.city == city)
        q = q.filter(BigView.zipCode == zipCode)

        results = q.fetch(10)
        for pickview in results:
            self.response.out.write('<blockquote>%s</blockquote>' % cgi.escape(q.addressNumber))

        self.render('searchindex.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few things wrong in your code, but probably easiest to give you an example of what to do.

Create a template like this (in "templates/searchindex.html"):

```
<html>
<body>
{% for result in results %}
<blockquote>{{ result }}</blockquote>
{% endfor %}
<body>
</html>
```

You need to initialize Jinja by putting this code at the top of your file (outside of all classes):

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader("templates"), # This is the directory where you store your templates
    autoescape=True
)
```

Then use the template in your code like this:

```
results = q.fetch(10)
template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template("searchindex.html")
self.response.write(template.render(dict(results=results)))
```

I haven't tested this, but it should at least get you close to fixing your code.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to consider using AJAX. Jinja2 is more likea templating language meaning not meant to for dynamic user interaction. So the way I see it is using Ajax if you want to return to server to validate things. So When the user submits the data in the form is will be sent to server and on success you display that the address is correct.

*I am demonstrating below using Flask; but the concept should apply.

something like the following:

assuming your html is:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
  $(function() {
    $('a#validateAddress').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/validate_address', {
        a: $('input[name="address"]').val()

      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
<h1>jQuery Example</h1>
<p><input type=text size=5 name=address>  
   <span id=result>?</span>
<p><a href=# id=validateAddress>Validate Address in DB</a>
```

on your server side (displaying using Flask):

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/validate_address')
def validate_address():
    address_from_client = request.args.get('address')
    **#Hit Your DB Here and Verify address is Right** the code above you wrote
    return jsonify(result="Valid")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```